# I want to convert textfield text into secure text like password when editing end(when user goes to next field) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I want to convert textfield text into secure text like password when editing end(basically when user goes to next field) in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Set that `UITextField` secure input.

```
secureField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

2.Or set delegate and change its text when editing begins or ends.

```
secureField.delegate = self

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if secureField == textField {
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if secureField == textField {
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegate Your textfield with view

and set this two methods

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField==self.txtEmail
    {
        self.txtEmail.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField==self.txtEmail
    {
        self.txtEmail.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

}
```